# Keyboard language getting change if i change the device language

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

I am developing an `iOS` application, in that i am facing a problem regarding the **decimal keyboard**, on one place on a `UITextField` i am showing decimal keyboard, but if i change the device language **English** to **French** then on **decimal keyboard** dot '.' change to comma ','. So my question is that , is there any way or any setting or any line of code by which device language wont affect on my application language's keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone: Change Keyboard language programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically)

Comment: please check my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for built in keyboard restricting localisation is not possible. Anyways you can handle the data gracefully. Just follow this link

[UITextField's numerical pad: dot instead of comma for float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150829/uitextfields-numerical-pad-dot-instead-of-comma-for-float-values)

or you can also make your own custom keyboard and set it as the keyboard type for your TextField. This would solve the problem once and for all.

Hope it helps you out.