# NumberFormatter, NSLocale, Xcode, iOS, Swift 3.0

Tags: xcode, swift3, nslocale, numberformatter

Problem: A textField with a "number" containing a decimal separator (a comma in my case), how can I change this to a decimal separator that Xcode will understand (.), and the other way around - display a result with the local decimal separator?

Ok...half way there...

```
let label = Input.text
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    let maybeNumber = formatter.number(from: label!)
    if maybeNumber != nil {
        Output.text = String(describing: maybeNumber!)
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked into `NumberFormatter`'s `decimalSeparator` property? You can set it to a (.) or (,) if that helps. Any more details or code samples might help us figure out exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30154625/2303865

Comment: Ok....half way there...let label = Input.text
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        let maybeNumber = formatter.number(from: label!)
        if maybeNumber != nil {
            
            Output.text = String(describing: maybeNumber!)
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can change the comma in the textField.text to a (.) by using this piece of code:

```
textField.text = textField.text.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
```

This finds the commas in your textField and replaces them with (.)

Comment: Thank you Michael and Morten; What I am trying to do is having a decimal number input with the Local Decimal Pad ("22,4"). Then change this to 22.4 for further calculations.....then again display the result in a Local decimal format.