# Flutter input with decimal number

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to parse input in Flutter and extract Double value there. I.e. user can only input decimal numbers.

To do this I'm using TextField:

```
TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: false, decimal: true)
                    controller: _controller,
                  )
```

However on iOS device I have keyboard with numbers and comma(,), not dot (.). When user inputs comma I'm parsing string and having error like this:

```
Error: FormatException: Invalid double 5,
```

What is the best way to handle this? 
Some dirty solutions are:

- use TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true) - this gives keyboard with not only numbers and user input dot there.
- maybe somehow replace commas with dots first

Answer (score 2):

In order to replace comma with dot when user is typing before onChanged callback (or validator) use `inputFormatters`

1. Create a new TextFormatter

```dart
class ReplaceCommaFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text.replaceAll(',', '.'),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

2. Use the new TextFormatter in the TextField

```dart
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
  inputFormatters: [
    ReplaceCommaFormatter(),
  ],
  onChanged: ((String? val) {
    // now to double will work correctly
  }),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason behind showing of the comma is because of the device's local region formats. Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150829/uitextfields-numerical-pad-dot-instead-of-comma-for-float-values) can help you out.