# Decimal Pad error with xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, textfield, uikeyboardtype

in xcode when I choose "Decimal Pad" Keyboard type for a textField I'm getting this error and I can use "point" in simulator but when testing on my iphone I can not use "point" It gave me "comma" how can I solve this problem.

> decimalPad[5087:358921] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-DecimalPad; using 2475421093446197222_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Comment: It depends on your regional settings. Your device's language may not be the same as simulator. For testing, you may change your device's language and region to English/US to see if the problem persists.

Comment: two of them's region is same "Turkey" and the error coming both simulator and my iphone

Comment: Yeah, I'm having the same problem. It's due to the fact that Turkish decimal system uses comma as the decimal "point", instead of point. As we can't control users' device regional/language settings, it's best to handle the app in such a way that it works with the current setting. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199438/decimal-point-in-calculations-as-or/15200028#15200028